# How to find id of clicked element

Tags: jquery

my code :

```
$('div').on('click',function(){
    checkEl = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(checkEl);
});
```

So each time div is clicked it schould throw a id of clicked element...

But.. on console.log i got like 3/4/5/6 elements depends from where i cliced...

My output is id of expected div but also parent div are displayed...

How to get id of exactly clicked element?

```js
$(function(){
$('div').on('click',function(){
    checkEl = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(checkEl);
    })
    })
```

```css
#main{
position:relative;
width:300px;
background-color:red;
}
div{
position:relative;
border:1px solid gray;
padding:15px;
width:100%:
}
#one{
background-color:black;
}
#two{
background-color:blue;
}#three{
background-color:orange;
}#four{
background-color:yellow;
}#fifth{
background-color:purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
<div id="one">
<div id="three">
<div id="four">
<div id="fifth">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Events bubble up the DOM tree; so clicking on `#fifth` will, in turn, pass that click event to every ancestor `<div>` element. (I'm not posting an answer because I'm sure this is a dupe, and I'm looking for that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that all of your nested divs have the onclick handler, so they all trigger. If you only want the innermost, you can use the following.

```
$('div').on('click',function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation()
    checkEl = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(checkEl);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Answer (score 3):

To avoid that the event is also triggered for parent elements, add a call to [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

```
$('div').on('click',function(e) {  // <-- argument
    checkEl = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(checkEl);
    e.stopPropagation(); // <---
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mitigate [event propagation](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-simplified-explanation-of-event-propagation-in-javascript-f9de7961a06e). Basically, since the DIVs are nested, the click event is called on the inner-most div and propagates up through the parent elements all the way to the DOCUMENT.

Calling [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) in the click event handler prevents this behavior.

```
$('div').on('click',function(event)
{
    checkEl = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(checkEl);
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('div').on('click',function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    checkEl = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(checkEl);
    })
})
```

Comment: It's always nice to put some explanation when you give an answer.